# Laravel redirect user if user is already logged in

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I have an application that has two authentications i.e user and admin.

I want to redirect the user to a specific page if they are already login. Like if the user is already logged in then the URL **http://example.com/log** should take the user to URL **http://example.com/dashboard**.

Similarly, if an admin is already logged in then, URL **http://example.com/admin/login** 
should redirect them to URL **http://example.com/admin/dashboard**.

The problem is I can change the handle method to redirect to only one page in RedirectIfAuthenticated page. Any idea on how to check if request is from admin or user in that page.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you create 2 guards for authentication like user and admin then simply check by below

```
    if (!Auth::guard('user')->user()) {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
    if (!Auth::guard('admin')->user()) {
         return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
    }
```

Comment: did you create 2 guards in config->auth.php like below                                        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'profile' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'profiles',
        ],